# Deserializing bytes to GenericRecord / Row

Tags: scala, apache-spark, deserialization, avro, parquet

In the aim of using `DataSourceV2` for reading some stored Parquet binary files that I have already their `Spark schema`, I am struggling to find a way to deserialize `Parquet` stream into `GenericRecord / Row`(s).

For `Avro` I found that we can do that using something like:

```
import org.apache.avro.generic.{GenericDatumReader, GenericRecord}
import org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroDeserializer

...

val datumReader = new GenericDatumReader[GenericRecord]()
val reader = DataFileReader.openReader(avroStream, datumReader)
val iterator = reader.iterator()
val record = iterator.next()
val row = AvroDeserializer(reader.getSchema, schema).deserialize(record)
```

where `avroStream` is a stream of bytes.

Is there some utility classes that can help?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why aren't you using built in readers and writers from Spark?

Comment: I said nothing about Hadoop... Spark reads local FS just fine

Comment: I don't want to use Hadoop FS, and for DataSourceV2 reader to work, the following methods must be implemented:

```
def next: Boolean = ???

def get: InternalRow = ???
```

from the Parquet stream I need to create a sequence/iterator of InternalRow

Comment: It is from a network stream. Thus I will be forced to save it locally first

Comment: Parquet requires a Hadoop Path and Configuration object, last time I checked. What type of network system are you reading from? What's wrong with saving it locally since you're required to read the whole parquet metadata header and footer to determine if it's even a valid file

Comment: additional overhead due to writing stream to a file that can be up to 1GB